# Pushing string vector to lua

Tags: c++, lua

I was trying to push string vector. But somehow it returns nil

Its my code:

```
static int Lua_Extract(lua_State* L) {

std::vector<std::string> foundedEvents;
foundedEvents.push_back("xx");

lua_createtable(L, foundedEvents.size(), 0);
        int newTable = lua_gettop(L);
        for (size_t i = 1; i < foundedEvents.size(); i++)
        {
            lua_pushstring(L, foundedEvents[i].c_str());
            lua_rawseti(L, newTable, i);
        }
return 1;
}
```

Comment: Given that `foundedEvents` has a single element, `i < foundedEvents.size()` is never true and your loop never executes. Make the loop start at 0 instead and pass `i+1` to `lua_rawseti`.